# I need to update a TableView every so often but doing so duplicates the cells

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `TableView` that I am updating from time to time with a Timer so that the data of the TableView changes if necessary... What happens is that the data is updated but it is duplicated and it does not eliminate the data that it had previously, then it is generating a giant TableView.

How could I make them update but delete the data I had previously and leave only the new cells when the tableview is updated?

This is the code that I use in the timer to update the TV:

```
 @objc func updatetableview(){
    databaseRef.child("A_Usuarios").queryOrdered(byChild: "TipoUsuario").queryEqual(toValue: "Empresa").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
       let key = snapshot.key
       self.snap = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!
       self.snap.setValue(key, forKey: "Uid")
       self.city = self.snap["Ciudad"] as? String ?? ""
       self.activo = self.snap["Activo"] as? String ?? ""
       if self.city == self.cdad && self.activo != "No" {
         if(key == self.loggedInUser?.uid){
            print("Same as logged in user, so don't show!")
         }
         else
         {
           self.usersArray.append(self.snap)
           //insert the rows
           self.tableview.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)],  with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
          }
        }

      }) { (error) in
             print(error.localizedDescription)
         }
```

I hope you can help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the array before doing another observe

```
@objc func updatetableview(){
 usersArray.removeAll()
 ....
}
```

BTW `.observe(.childAdded` is supposed to do the job , so you may need n't to do this

Comment: This crashes the application... This is the error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)."

Comment: Solved this using your code and adding tableview.reloadData()... Thanks.

Comment: this is temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

The observer you have used returns all the values in the given path. This closure is called when a new child is added. But it gets all the available in that path, not only the newly added data.

This is why it is generating a giant TableView.

So you need to get the newly added data only using `queryLimited(toLast: UInt)`

```
databaseRef.child("A_Usuarios").queryOrdered(byChild: "TipoUsuario").queryEqual(toValue: "Empresa").queryLimited(toLast: 1).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Answer (score 0):

In firebase, if you are observing same node 5 times then it will give you 5 events. So you are adding same record 5 times. So you need to check that you are already observing that node before observing. Following code creating a problem. Every time you call updateTableView. It is adding new observer and that why you get same records multiple times.

```
    databaseRef.child("A_Usuarios").queryOrdered(byChild: "TipoUsuario").queryEqual(toValue: "Empresa").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Comment: You need to keep track already added abservers in our case ie. "A_Usuarios/TipoUsuario/". Before registering any firebase observer you need to check you are listening already that node or not (using your logic). If not then only register new observer.